# How Sorting a String by ASCII order

Tags: c++

I just make a program to sort a string in alphabetically order, but i have problem if i am input number it's not shown in output . How i sort in ASCII order. Any one can help ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort_string(char*);

int main()
{
   char string[100];

   printf("Enter some text\n");
   gets(string);

   sort_string(string);
   printf("%s\n", string);

   return 0;
}

void sort_string(char *s)
{
   int c, d = 0, length;
   char *pointer, *result, ch;

   length = strlen(s);

   result = (char*)malloc(length+1);

   pointer = s;

   for ( ch = 'A' ; ch <= 'z' ; ch++ ) // i don't know how add range
   {
      for ( c = 0 ; c < length ; c++ )
      {
         if ( *pointer == ch )
         {
            *(result+d) = *pointer;
            d++;
         }
         pointer++;
      }
      pointer = s;
   }
   *(result+d) = '\0';

   strcpy(s, result);
   free(result);
}
```

Sorry if my code still bad, i am still learn c++

Comment: What do you mean in alphabetical order? You know that 'A' to 'z' also adds characters such as '[', ']', '/', etc? Do you only need letters and numbers? Do you need spaces? I wonder why you would want to sort a string. Anyway, here's the ascii table, hope this helps : http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: use `std::sort`? or you've to write your own function? If yes, which sorting technique you're trying to implement?

Comment: implicit `int` has never been valid in C++. Fixed the implicit `int` for `main`.

Comment: This should probably be tagged as C and not C++. Please make sure you are asking about the correct language here! C and C++ are not the same...

Comment: I think you mean lexicographic order (treating char as an integer), not alphabetical order (choosing a set of characters and defining an ordering for them).

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), the number '0' starts on 0x30 and ends with a '9' at 0x39. In your loop, the first letter starts with an 'A', on 0x41.
Just start your loop from '0' to 'z', and it'll include the numbers too. (It will also include signs such as <, @, etc...)